Styling scrollbars in non-webkit based browsers
Is there an pseudo-element or property to style scrollbars in browsers that are not webkit based? like firefox.
Like in webkit based browsers, this can be done.
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    ...
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    ...
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    ...
}

